# Переход из фрагмента в активити по кнопке

Tags: java, android-studio

Не получается реализовать переход из фрагмента в активити по кнопке. Перерыв весь интернет, решила попросить о помощи, т.к. не могу писать приложение дальше

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_setting, container, false);
    }

public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent=new Intent(Setting.this,SettingBD.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

//--------------
(Setting.this,SetttingBD.class); ----всегда подчеркнут красным

```
cannot resolve constructor "intent(com.wb.myapplication.Setting,java.land.Class<com.wb.myapplication.SettingBD>)
```

Comment: Вам студия пишет, что параметры конструктора неверные. Что за Setting.this? Попробуйте просто this.

Comment: первым аргументом интента должен быть контекст, ваш класс Setting таким не является (this вместо контекста можно указывать только для активити, так как этот класс наследуется от контекста) Для фрагмента первым аргументом вы можете указать метод getActivity() или getContext()

Comment: Setting.this и просто this  все равно подчеркивает.  public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button3:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingBD.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
Это в ActivityMAin.java. Ничего не работает, нажимаю на кнопку - ноль

Comment: `Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),SettingBD.class);`

Comment: Не работает все равно. Ошибок нет, но по кнопке не открывается( кнопку описывала)

Comment: И приложение вылетает

Comment: Все работает. Всем спасибо

Comment: если вы решили проблему, то было бы хорошо оформить ответ с ее решением. Это позволит другим людям с аналогичной проблемой получить решение не дожидаясь чей то помощи, а просто прочитав ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_setting, null);
```

//**********Переход из фрагмента Setting в activity  SettingBD*******************

```
Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),SettingBD.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

//******************************************************************************

```
}
```